# Spring cloud kafka Stream Binder transactionIdPrefix performance hit

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

We have a kafka process where we are consuming messages from one topic then there is some enrichment happening and then we are publishing the message to another topic. below are the events

- Consumer - Consume the message
- Enrichment - Enriched the consumed message
- Producer - Published Enriched message to other topic

I am using Spring cloud kafka binder version 3.0.0-RELEASE and things are working fine. Recently we introduced idempotent producer and included transactionIdPrefix property and we observed that we started getting performance issue. Below is the stats.

- Before transactionIdPrefix system was taking around 20 seconds to processed 10k messages with 30 concurrent consumer. which is 500 messages per second.
- After transactionIdPrefix system is taking avg 165 seconds for 10k messages with 30 concurrent consumer. which is 60 messages per second.

below is the code and config we have.

```
@StreamListener("INPUT")
@SendTo("OUTPUT")
public void consumer(Message message){
Acknowledgement ack = messge.getHeaders().get(KafkaHeaders.ACKNOWLEDGEMENT,Acknowledgement.class))
try{
    String inputMessage = message.getPayload.toString();
    String enrichMessage = // Enrichment on inputMessage
    ack.acknowledgement()   
    return enrichMessage;
}catch( Exception exp){
    ack.acknowledgement();
    throw exp;  
}
}
```

Configs are

1. spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.transaction.transactionIdPrefix=TX-
2. spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.transaction.producer.configuration.ack=all
3. spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.transaction.producer.configuration.retries=10
4. spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.consumer.autoCommitOffset=false
5. spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.consumer.concurrency=30
6. spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.consumer.enableDlq=true
7. spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.consumer.dlqName=error.topic
8. spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.consumer.autoCommitOnError=true
9. spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.consumer.maxAttempt=3
10. spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.transaction.producer.configuration.enable.idempotence=true

I expect little bit performance hit but this looks to be a huge performance difference. Has anybody encountered such issue and any suggestion how we can improve the performance with transactionIdPrefix attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Transactions are always expensive; especially when only performing one write for each read.

Using the functional model (`Consumer<Message>` instead of `@StreamListener`), you can enable batch mode to receive a `List<Message>`; this should help with performance.

```
public Consumer<List<Message>> () {
    messages -> {...}
}
```

That way, the transaction will apply to the whole list.

Comment: That should make sense. I should have thought that. BTW using Consumer<List<Message>> I can consume messages in batches. As I have to publish the messages as well, Is there any way to publish the bulk messages? Else I'll have to use OutboundChannel to send individual messages.

Comment: Use `StreamBridge`. https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.4/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_sending_arbitrary_data_to_an_output_e_g_foreign_event_driven_sources send them one at a time and they will all participate in the transaction.